# How to connect to localhost from OperaMini

Tags: opera, localhost, blackberry

I'm trying to develop a BlackBerry compatible web page (using OperaMini), but OperaMini seems to avoid connecting with localhost:

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.2.107(ipaddres given by the router)

I'm using OperaMini 4.x and MicroEmulator 2.0.4. Is there another way to develop for mobile phones(BlackBerry mainly)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OperaMini uses a [transcoding proxy server](http://www.opera.com/mini/help/faq/#cryptcomm) to retrieve *light* versions of website for the phone.  Because all traffic goes through this proxy server, OperaMini cannot access anything on the local machine or network.  In order for OperaMini to have access it must be available on the internet.

This has also been discussed on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/61606/let-opera-mini-in-microemulator-on-os-x-hit-local-network).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have the [MDS emulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp) installed and running.  BlackBerry emulators by default cannot connect to the internet, remote or local.  The MDS emulator will simulate the BlackBerry network.